# How do I navigate to a site in Selenium with this certain path?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is the line of code I initiate the browser with:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe')
```

I use this because I want to have my regular browser etc. Otherwise I would have used:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Now, my problem is that when I use the method "browser.get('link')", it does not redirect the page to the specified link. (Which did not happen with the second line of code specified here!) What do you suggest I do to solve this problem? As I said, I am only after retaining the cookies etc.

Answer (score 0):

Through the *key* `executable_path` instead the absolute path of **chrome.exe** you need to pass the absolute path of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) executable. So your effective line of code will be:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: But the problem I get then is my Chrome profile is not transferred! What should I do to fix this?

Comment: @DeltaFoxtrot Sounds like a completely different issue all together. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.